# lazy load in React

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I know about lazy loading a component like:

```
import React, { lazy } from "react";
const Search = lazy(() => import('./components/search/Search'));
```

I was wondering how to handle imports like this with lazy?

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
```

Answer (score 4):

`lazy` expects a promise of `{ default: ... }` object to be returned.

In case a module doesn't follow this convention, a component should be re-exported as `default` in intermediate module:

```
export { ToastContainer as default, toast } from 'react-toastify';
```

Or handled in `lazy` function:

```
lazy(async () => {
  const { ToastContainer } = await import('react-toastify');
  return { default: ToastContainer };
});
```

Comment: how to import 'toast' then? I need to import both ToastContainer and toast.I tried this:              
lazy(async () => {
    const { ToastContainer, toast } = await import('react-toastify');
    return { default: ToastContainer, toast };
});                but no luck, it looks as if toast is not imported

Comment: Where do you intend to use `toast`? The question doesn't contain relevant code. `lazy` results in lazy-loaded *component*.

Comment: got it, Thanks.